# ssh/mosh to a remote interactive shell and run specific function

Tags: ssh, zsh, oh-my-zsh, mosh

I have the following alias on my local machine:

```
alias gom='mosh -- user@host  "/path/to/specific/zsh"'
```

I use it to connect to a remote machine with an interactive shell. I would like to **modify this alias** to run a specific function `my_func` defined in `.zshenv` **in the remote machine** as soon as I log in on it (when using this alias).

How can I do so?

I have tried the following:

- `alias gom='mosh -- user@host  "/path/to/specific/zsh"; my_func;'`
- `alias gom='mosh -- user@host  "/path/to/specific/zsh; my_func"'`
- `alias gom='mosh -- user@host  "/path/to/specific/zsh & my_func"'`

Some of the above solutions disconnect me from the remote sessions, while others don't, but none of them work.

Comment: Why don't call the function inside `.zshrc`?

Comment: Thanks @cuonglm. It's not an option for reasons that I can't easily explain. I need to do it when, and only when I connect using this alias.

Comment: I think you can't. `/path/to/specific/zsh` spawn a interactive shell, then you must call `my_func` explicitly. For non-interactive shell, you can `mosh -- user@host  /path/to/specific/zsh -c "my_func"'`

Answer (score 2):

```
% exec zsh
% MAGIC=1 exec zsh
hello world
% grep -1 hw .zshrc

function hw { print "hello world" }
[[ -n $MAGIC ]] && hw

%
```

So uh remotely

```
% ssh localhost "MAGIC=1 zsh -i"
```

or something